# Series n-th root, converges/diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this series $\sum_{n=1}^\inf (-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{3}-1)$ and I have to show, whether it cconverges, converges absolutely or diverges. I have already managed to prove, that it converges (using Leibniz) but I don´t know, how to show whether it converges absolutely. More precisely, I don´t how to show that $\sum (\sqrt[n]{3}-1)$ diverges.

Thanks for your help

Comment: To show it diverges, use the mean value theorem to bound the terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\forall n,\ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\leqslant\mathrm e\implies\forall n,\ \sqrt[n]{3}-1\geqslant\frac1n\implies\sum_n\left(\sqrt[n]{3}-1\right)=+\infty$$