# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt[n]{2}-1\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to determine whether $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left ( \sqrt[n]{2}-1\right )$$ converges or diverges.  Ratio, root, nth term, etc tests are either inconclusive or too difficult to simplify.  I feel like there must be something I can bound this series by but I can't think what.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090716/series-n-th-root-converges-diverges) the answerer very smartly (I have no idea how he/ she thought to do that) used the fact that $(1+\frac 1n)^n \le e \le 3$ to bound $\sqrt[n]{3} -1$ by $\frac 1n$ but that only worked because $3\ge e$.  So even though that question looks very similar I don't think I can apply that idea here.

Edit: This is in the section before power/ Taylor series so I don't think I'm allowed to use that.

Comment: You can use the inequality $e^x - 1 \ge x$, this can be proved using IVT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sqrt[n]{2}-1 = e^{\frac{\log{2}}{n}} - 1 = \frac{\log{2}}{n} + O(n^{-2})$$

as $n \to \infty$.

**ADDENDUM**

To address your specific problem, consider instead

$$\left (1+\frac{\log{2}}{n} \right )^n $$

which you should be able to show is less than $2$.  I that case, then you can show that $\sqrt[n]{2}-1 \gt (\log{2})/n$ and draw your conclusion about the sum.

Comment: We haven't gotten to Taylor series yet, so I don't think I'm allowed to use that.

Comment: It's more than hint..

Comment: You don't need Taylor's theorem to know $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

An extension of Bernoulli's Inequality says
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]2
&=\left(1-\frac12\right)^{-1/n}\tag{1a}\\
&\ge1+\frac1{2n}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\sqrt[n]2-1\ge\frac1{2n}\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt[n]2-1\right)
\ge\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\tag3
$$
which diverges.

---

**An Extension of Bernoulli's Inequality**

Bernoulli's Inequality is first introduced as $(1+x)^a\ge1+ax$ where $x\gt-1$ and $a\ge1$. However, for $x\gt-1$ and $a\ge0$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{-a}
&=(1+x)\left(1-\frac x{1+x}\right)^{a+1}\tag{4a}\\
&\ge(1+x)\left(1-\frac{(a+1)x}{1+x}\right)\tag{4b}\\[3pt]
&=1-ax\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ $(1+x)^{-a}=(1+x)(1+x)^{-a-1}=(1+x)\left(1-\frac x{1+x}\right)^{a+1}$
$\text{(4b):}$ since $x\gt-1$, we have $-\frac x{1+x}\gt-1$
$\phantom{\text{(4b):}}$ apply Bernoulli for $a+1\ge1$
$\text{(4c):}$ simplify

Thus, Bernoulli's Inequality holds for all negative exponents.

---

**A Reversal of Bernoulli's Inequality**

For $x\gt-1$ and $0\lt a\le1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+ax\right)^{1/a}&\ge1+x\tag{5a}\\
1+ax&\ge(1+x)^a\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a):}$ Bernoulli for $1/a\ge1$
$\text{(5b):}$ raise both sides to the power $a$

Thus, we have the reversal of Bernoulli's Inequality for exponents $0\lt a\le1$.

Comment: Although we don't use the reversal of Bernoulli's inequality in this answer, I thought it would be good to complete the exponent coverage for all reals, just to have a place for reference.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n\geq1$
$$2^{1/n}-1=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (2^{1/n})^k\right)^{-1}\geq\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2n}.$$
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}$ diverges so does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^{1/n}-1)$.

Comment: (+1) This gives the same result as my answer, and it doesn't use logarithms or series. It does require $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, but who knows what the OP wanted? (they only showed up to ask this one question)